# VBSQL.OCX is not registered -ERROR

Tags: vb6, activex, regsvr32

I have two test machines say machine A and B (both 64 bit) .There is a VB6 application which uses the Vbsql OLE Custom control module (Vbsql.ocx).

That VB application runs fine without any errors in machine A but it fails with the below error message when executed in Machine B.

[image]

Note: I copied the ocx file from machine A to register it on machine B but it couldn't  be registered the error screenshot is like below.

[image]

Both machines doesn't have VB6 IDE so I could be able to debug.

Comment: Use the `Dependency Walker` tool on the client system to determine what DLL is missing on the client system and copy it into the same directory of the client system as the .OCX and try rerunning it - http://www.dependencywalker.com

Comment: Thanks.In my case it is clear that VBSQL.OCX is the problem and missing.Why does it failed to load when registered again?

Comment: @jeyaganesh: As Petesh said, it might be that the OCX requires other DLLs which are also missing on your system. That's where Dependency Walker comes to play.

Comment: Vbsql.ocx was a component designed to run with SQL Server version 6.5.  That was *seventeen* years and *five* major releases ago.  This is not like fine wine, it doesn't get better with age.  Use a virtual machine to run ancient software.

Comment: Well said @HansPassant.But what matters so much is that it runs perfectly fine in Machine A.

Comment: I used the dependency walker application on the ocx file and both the machines show the same number of DLLs missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to register the VBSQL.OCX file.

Using dependency walker I figured out NTWDBLIB.dll file is missing in machine B so copied into SYSWOW64 folder and registered using the elevated command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the 32-bit version of `regsvr32`?

```
%WINDIR%\...\SysWOW64\regsvr32 vbsql.ocx
```

The 64-bit version won't load this (presumably) 32-bit DLL.

Comment: I already tried this to register using the syswow64 but getting the same error message

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ocx file in the same directory as your executable.

Comment: I have that OCX file in the same directory , still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

[image: Use following Run command in order to register OCX]

Use following Run command in order to register OCX